# How I can use Rails ActiveRecord::Migration method table_name_options() for set table prefix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I tried to use this method in inflections.rb:

```
 ActiveRecord::Migration.table_name_options ( {table_name_prefix: 'tg_', table_name_suffix: ''})
```

or

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.table_name_prefix = 'tg_'
```

but it does not work.

Comment: how did you use it? can you post the actual migration file?